# How can I repeat the Math.random process until the number is below 0.5? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, random

```
var randomNum = Math.random();

if(randomNum<0.5){
    console.log("it will always be me.");
    console.log(randomNum);
}

else if(randomNum>=0.5){
    **//what do I do here to repeat the Math.random process until the number is below 0.5?**
}
```

I am new to using JavaScript and I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I want it to work so that when a number above 0.5 is picked, it repeats the Math.random process without doing anything else until a number below 0.5 is picked. So that in the end it will always display "it will always be me.", and the number that was picked. Is this possible? If so, can someone to tell me how to do it?

Comment: Why would you do this, as opposed to just taking the result of `Math.random` and scaling it to fit within the desired range?

Comment: If all you want is a random number between 0 & 0.5, why not take the result of Math.random() and divide by 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why you would want to do this, but a while loop seems like the best fit:

```
var randomNum = Math.random();
while(randomNum >= 0.5){
   randomNum = Math.random()
}
console.log("it will always be me.");
console.log(randomNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't actually want to complete your problem this way, but if you do you should use a while loop. If you just need to get a random number below .5, you can just divide by 2.

```
var randomNum = Math.random();
while(randomNum >= .05){
    randomNum = Math.random();
}
```